# wrapfigures and quote environment not working together

Tags: page-breaking, wrapfigure, quoting

I want to have a figure floating next to a block quote. So I used the [`wrapfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) package and the `quote` environment.

If you typeset the following example, you will see that the figure is printed on the next page instead of being next to the block quote. It works perfectly with normal text. Is there any solution to that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}
    \blindtext[3]
    \begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \rule{5cm}{5cm}
        \caption{Foo bar foobar baz baq}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \begin{quote}
        \blindtext
    \end{quote}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to work OK using `r` instead of `R` (lowercase specifiers don't allow the object to float); I also added some value for the hanging indentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}
    \blindtext[3]
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}[-10pt]{0.5\textwidth}
        \vspace*{\topsep}
        \centering
        \rule{5cm}{5cm}
        \caption{Foo bar foobar baz baq}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \begin{quote}
        \blindtext
    \end{quote}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice the additional `\vspace*{\topsep}` inside `wrapfigure`; in this case, this is necessary to have the top of the figure aligned with the top of the first line of the `quote` environment (thanks to **barbara beeton** for suggesting this improvement).

Comment: Thanks, but it only works with the indentation! Otherwise I get [this](http://upload.ps0ke.de/images/wrapfig-vs-quote-r.png).

Comment: @Ps0ke I don't understand your comment. My code produces the effect illustrated in the image I attached; if you are still experiencing undesired results, please edit your question and add some complete and minimal document  illustrating the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I must've made a mistake. Your code works perfectly--with or with out the indentaion.

Comment: @Ps0ke ah, OK then.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina -- is there any way to have the top of the figure aligned with the top of the first line of the quote?  it would look nicer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton you're right. I added the necessary code. Thank you!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I'm sorry, I usually upvote helpful comments, but strangely I wasn't allowed to yesterday because of to few reputation. I did it now :)

Comment: @Ps0ke no need to apologize! Thanks for up-voting :-)